# Parse Server memory issue

Tags: node.js, express, memory, memory-leaks, parse-server

im started monitoring the memory usage on my Parse Server hosted on the Google Cloud Platform's Compute Engine, its a pretty big application with over 180 cloud functions.

PARSE-SERVER: v2.8.4

I noticed the memory usage slowly creeps up, before dropping and repeating the process, where the CPU ramps up. Is this to be expeced or shoud I investigate a memory leak (If so, how should go about on doing it)? Its worh noting that the application runs fine, it doesn't crash, drop traffic  or anything.

[image: GCP monitoring tool]

My server initialization is pretty standard, I then have cloud functions in place:

```
var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: process.env.DATABASE_URI,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL
});

var app = express();

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.timeout = 60 * 1000;
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of `parse-server` are you using? The is a [merge](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/7214) that solves a memory leak (don't know if related to your issue, though).

Comment: It could be, Im running version 2.8.4, I'll give it a try, thanks!